# How to move to next json item in a json array via Onclicklistener

Tags: java, android, json, onclicklistener

I have two Button mPrevious and mNext. I'm trying to move to the next item in my json array with an OnclickListener and I so confused. The data in the array are strings that include a URL and String text.The mPrevious button should take position back by -1 but if currentPosition is 0 return 0.

```
  "Team": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "Name": "Leo Messi",
        "Position": "Forward",
        "videoURL": "www.youtube.com/watch?v=messi",
        "thumbnailURL": ""
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "Name": "Cristiano Ronaldo",
        "Postion": "Forward",
        "videoURL": "www.youtube.com/watch?v=ronaldo",
        "thumbnailURL": ""
      },





mNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                for (int i = 0; i < TeamListOj.getmTeam().size(); i++) {
                    i++;

                }

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a global static variable where you stock your current index.
In the OnClickListener increment this variable and you have your current index.

Maybe not the best solution but hope it helps

Edit:
Here is some code:

```html
static int currentIndex = 0;

mNext.setOnclickListener(...

  {
    //TODO check if index exceeds array size
    currentIndex++;
    String aString = myArray[currentIndex];
  }
 );
```

Comment: also check the size for array index out of bound exception

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a custom class instead of a JSONArray?

I'd convert your "Player" json to a class and your "team" array to a list. For example, using Java class Linked List, you could simply get the next element by calling "next()" on any item.

Edit:

Here is how your class would look like, you should add getters and setters.

```
public class Player {
    private String videoURL;

    private String Position;

    private String id;

    private String Name;

    private String thumbnailURL;
}
```

Now, with Gson converter, you can just get an instance of this class by doing:

```
String json = "YOUR_JSON_HERE";

Gson gson = new Gson();

Car car = gson.fromJson(json, Player.class);
```

Comment: Can I get a snippet Please?

Comment: I recommend using a converter, like Gson (https://github.com/google/gson).

Comment: Edited answer with some snippets

Comment: I already have such a class. but my issue is how do I set the iteration method in the onClicklistener coz currently the code I've written is defunct. (sorry, been away)